# How to avoid timeout exception in zuul using .yml

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have zuul gateway server without eureka service discovery.

I connect the microservice and zuul using the yml file shown below.

When I execute the URL timeout exception occurs

ava.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91] at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_91] at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_91] at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_91] at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4] at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4] at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4] at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4] at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4] at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4] at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4] at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2] at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:324) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:287) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:173) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE] at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0] at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0] at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0] at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0] at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0] at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0] at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:261) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]

```
   server:
   port: 9090

   eureka:
   client:
   enabled: false

zuul:
    #Service will be mapped under the /api URI
    prefix: /clo-services/rest
    stripPrefix: false
    #Uncomment to disable auto-registering all services read from Eureka
    #ignoredServices: '*'
     routes:
     proposals:
     path: /**/proposals/**
     url: http://localhost:6004
     stripPrefix: false
   common:
     path: /**/common/**
     url: http://localhost:8090
     stripPrefix: false
   host:
     connect-timeout-millis: 5000
     socket-timeout-millis: 10000

      hystrix:
        command:
          default:
   execution:
       isolation:
      thread:
        timeoutInMilliseconds: 6000


    spring:
        application:
             name: zuul-server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    zuul:
      host:
        connect-timeout-millis: 20000
        socket-timeout-millis: 60000
```